# Create a .csv of list of number of non null cell from raster in a mapset

Tags: grass-gis, csv, list, cell-statistics

How can I create a .csv file (maybe output of a function) of number of non null cells of raster from a given list in GRASS (e.g. rasters could be: `myraster#1... myraster#500`)?
Unfortunately `g.list` cannot print the number of non-null cells, so I was thinking to a loop as:

```
for Raster in 'g.list rast pattern=myraster* mapset=mymapset'

do eval 'r.univar map="$Raster" '

$n << path/to/my/non_null_cells.csv

done
```

where `n` is the number of non-null cells from every raster.

But, even in this case, doing like this I would only overwrite each `n` with the subsequent in the .csv.
Is there any proper command/function? Should I create a vector and then export that vector to a .csv?

Comment: Count null cells, subtract from total cells?

Comment: r.stats works for it